# How do I use Truffle to deploy a contract on ThunderCore?

Tags: truffle, thundercore

How do I use Truffle to deploy a contract on ThunderCore?
Is it the same as using truffle on ethereum? how do I setup the config? Is there any document or resource to reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your Truffle project to:

1. Use [`@truffle/hdwallet-provider`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider) and point it at https://mainnet-rpc.thundercore.com
2. Set `byzantium` as the target EVM version for the Solidity compiler

   - See `evnVersion` in `truffle-config.js` below
   - ThunderCore supports `byzantium` as of April 2020

## Self-contained Project Template

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "field-support",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "trufflej-config.js",
  "license": "LicenseRef-COPYING",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "json5": "^2.1.0",
    "truffle": "^5.1.22",
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.34"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "truffle test",
    "migrate": "truffle migrate",
    "deploy": "truffle migrate",
    "compile": "truffle compile",
    "build": "truffle build",
    "lint": "solium -d contracts && eslint ."
  },
  "keywords": [
    "smart contract"
  ],
  "author": ""
}
```

`truffle-config.js`

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

const fs = require("fs");

const MAINNET_PROVIDER = "https://mainnet-rpc.thundercore.com";

let privateKeys = null;
let mnemonic = null;
try {
  privateKeys = fs
    .readFileSync(".private-keys", { encoding: "ascii" })
    .split("\n")
    .filter(x => x.length > 0);
} catch (err) {
  if (err.code !== "ENOENT") {
    throw err;
  }
}

if (!privateKeys) {
  try {
    mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".mnemonic", { encoding: "ascii" }).trim();
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code !== "ENOENT") {
      throw err;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    // For `truffle develop`
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 9545, // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*" // Any network (default: none)
    },
    "thunder-mainnet": {
      provider: () => {
        if (privateKeys === null && mnemonic === null) {
          throw new Error("Please create a .private-keys or .mnemonic file");
        }

        return privateKeys
          ? new HDWalletProvider(
              privateKeys,
              MAINNET_PROVIDER,
              0, // <- change address_index if you want to use non-first address
              privateKeys.length
            )
          : new HDWalletProvider(
              mnemonic,
              MAINNET_PROVIDER,
              0 // <- change address_index if you want to use non-first address
            );
      },
      network_id: "108"
    }
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.9", // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      settings: {
        // see the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmversion
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 200
        },
        evmVersion: "byzantium" // Current evm on ThunderCore fixed at "byzantium"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

`contracts/SimplStorage.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.5;

contract SimpleStorage {
  uint storedData;

  function set(uint x) public {
    storedData = x;
  }

  function get() public view returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

`migrations/2_deploy.js`

```
const SimpleStorage = artifacts.require('SimpleStorage');

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage);
};
```

## Sample Session

1. Create [a wallet in Metamask](https://www.thundercore.com/wallet-instructions/)
2. Get Thunder Tokens (TT) through the ThunderCore [Mainnet Faucet](https://faucet.thundercore.com/)
3. Export the private key and save it to a `.private-keys` file
4. Run `truffle migrate --network thunder-mainnet`:

```
$ truffle migrate --network thunder-mainnet

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'thunder-mainnet'
> Network id:      108
> Block gas limit: 0x5f5e100


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x4d943a338d683d7ba0dc4937417b4b795b4791849b4695aeddb8811bdb265183
   > Blocks: 5            Seconds: 6
   > contract address:    0xFAc8a9a57cb2C70059D603f393F4A4f830C43a34
(...)

   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.00554924 ETH


2_deploy.js
===========

   Deploying 'SimpleStorage'
   -------------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x8a6063fa9dd74935e0db262a03ffee38181e383e3d73dd408cc76730e79ac135
   > Blocks: 5            Seconds: 6
   > contract address:    0x75F89Ba793DDFFCA4b604Ae8B28E8DfD8Dbbe14a
(...)
```

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/thundercore/field-support/tree/simple-storage) in the `simple-storage` branch of the `field-support` repo.